# FontAwesome inside React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

I am trying to insert font-awesome icons inside react, where I want to set the placeholder of input as search icon

```
const Search = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="Search">
        <form className="Search__form">
          <img src="" />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="&#xF002; Search"
            style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome"
          ></input>

          <button>Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

I got this error

Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because JSX is not HTML, in JSX you have to pass style as an Object, and to use javascript we have to put a `{}` and then inside first `{}` put your styles in an object, but style keys should be in camelCase

Eg:

- background-color: green => backgroundColor: 'green'

```
const Search = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="Search">
        <form className="Search__form">
          <img src="" />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="&#xF002; Search"
            style={{fontFamily:"Arial, FontAwesome"}}
          ></input>

          <button>Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Done mate, thanks for your help, and can you vote too for my question to help other too.